# iOS app crash recover method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asynchronous, download

Since 2 yrs I have been trying different ways to find the solution of app crash while click back button.

My application scenario:

In a tableview contoller I have to load list of users, On view did load I call getData(Asyncronous download) API method to load data. At the time of data download, If user press back button my application gets crash due to null value objects. That says all of my variable memory deallocated.

To overcome this problem, I used some loading indicator which lock UIScreen untill data download.

Questions:

1. Is there any alternatives to prevent crash, UIScreen Lock
2. Other applications use Activity Indicator in Menu bar without UIScreen Lock. How they are doing?

Need help to recover this issue

Here is my sample code to download data :
Below code doesnt crash app. But it download data even I cancel operations on dealloc
**viewDidLoad:**

```
ShowNetworkActivityIndicator();
_processQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
_processQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;
_processQueue.name = @"Events Processing";
[self loadData];
```

loadData:

-(void)loadData
{
    [_processQueue addOperationWithBlock: ^ {

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all"]]; 
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];



    NSDictionary *search = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^ {
        _countryListArray=[search mutableCopy];
        [self.tableViewSample reloadData];
        HideNetworkActivityIndicator();
    }];

}];
```

}

I tried cancelAllOperations in dealloc:

```
[_processQueue setSuspended:YES];
[_processQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: Unfortunately don't have time to give a complete answer right now but basically: Create NSOperation to fetch data async, only populate table view when AS data arrives.

Comment: please paste some code on how you fetch and assign the data

Comment: You can cancel your network operation when the view controller deallocated.

Comment: How to cancel network operation? it run async concept

Comment: @Tommy what do you expect from those two methods `setSuspended:` and `cancelAllOperations` ? Might want to check the documentation in regards of what they do and what you need to add in order to finish the solution. Right now you only prevent next operations from being started, which is good but that wasn't a problem, and set a flag which you never check.

Comment: Have you tried using an `NSURLSession` rather than `NSURLConnection`?

Comment: In my app I planned to run one operation Per ViewController. Why should i check for flag status? @A-Live can you explain me clearly

Comment: @Tommy Even better, I'll help you find the official documentation: [NSOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/) docs explaining use of `cancel` and `isCancelled`, it also has a reference to even more detailed [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html). And of course for `setSuspended` you'll want to check the documentation of `NSOperationQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try inserting the reload data is dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main(),void (^){}); callback , main thread , I think the reload happening in the background thread is crashing the app.

`[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^ { _countryListArray=[search mutableCopy];  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.tableViewSample reloadData];
        HideNetworkActivityIndicator();
});}];`

Comment: Current code works without crash. I want to cancel my operation in dealloc